# Orthogonal Matrix filled according to function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to create an orthogonal matrices in Python to visualize the decline of a signal according to the distance from the source and the angle to the source.
For simplicity we can describe the decline:

```
NewValue = cos(angle)*(StartingValue – a*(distance))
```

I found that Scipy.stats has ortho_group, which can be used to create random orthogonal matrices:

```
 from scipy.stats import ortho_group

 x = ortho_group.rvs(3)
 np.dot(x, x.T)

 # returns:
 array([[  1.00000000e+00,   1.13231364e-17,  -2.86852790e-16],
        [  1.13231364e-17,   1.00000000e+00,  -1.46845020e-16],
        [ -2.86852790e-16,  -1.46845020e-16,   1.00000000e+00]])

 import scipy.linalg
 np.fabs(scipy.linalg.det(x))
 # returns:
 1.0
```

Since a random matrix isn’t really useful, I keep wondering how I can create a orthogonal matrix with values according to my function.

A second challenge, I’m encountering is how to limit the range of the matrix to a range of angles of 0-45° degrees.

Comment: You need to explain how the values generated by your function relate to the orthogonal matrix.